# HyphenationConfig for iText7

Tags: java, itext

I want to set hyphenation "-" to the end of line. It throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    try {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(file));
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        createPDF(document);
        pdfDocument.close();
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Create method

```
private static void createPDF(Document document) {
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(
            "If you can distribute the content over different pages you would need to insert a ...");
    paragraph.add("Based on the value of fits, you can decide to change the size of the rectangle or the content.");
    paragraph.add("In this example, area contains the coordinates of the desired rectangle.");
    paragraph.add("One part of a situation , idea, plan etc that has many parts.");
    paragraph.add("It's defined by which horizontal or vertical slice of the world you connect 10000yourself with.");
    HyphenationConfig hyphenationConfig = new HyphenationConfig("en", "US", 2, 2);
    paragraph.setHyphenation(hyphenationConfig);
    document.add(paragraph);
}
```

When I rund the code, it throws exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
at com.itextpdf.layout.hyphenation.Hyphenation.getPreHyphenText(Hyphenation.java:59)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TextRenderer.layout(TextRenderer.java:381)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.layout(LineRenderer.java:298)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.layout(ParagraphRenderer.java:193)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:124)
at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.createAndAddRendererSubTree(RootElement.java:377)
at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:106)
at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.add(Document.java:143)
at columntext.TestHyphenation.createPDF(TestHyphenation.java:43)
at columntext.TestHyphenation.main(TestHyphenation.java:24)
```

It causes by the end of character is "10000yourself", some characters need to be show in next line.

When the content contains "10000 yourself", it can generate PDF normally.
[image]
But when the content contains "10000yourself", it throws exception.

The version of itext is "7.1.1", dependency see following

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdftest</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please **a** describe what is terrible and **b** give the stack trace of the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I executed your document creation code and did not get an exception.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I'm a novice. The version of itext7 is 7.1.0, it's the latest version.

Comment: There at least is a 7.1.1. I've tested with the current development snapshot. That being said, I just downgraded dependencies of my test project to 7.1.0 and still didn't get that exception.

Comment: Do you have any add-ons installed? Like pdfCalligraph?

Comment: It's strange. I didn't add other add-ons for this example.